# WSO2 BAM with JMS

Tags: jms, wso2, wso2-bam

The official BAM documentation states that BAM can receive events over Apache Thrift, REST, HTTP and Web services. Strangely JMS is not in the list ? while both CEP & ESB allow JMS transport.

I wanted to know is there anyway JMS can be enabled on BAM,we would like to publish our
events over JMS and have BAM pick 'em up from the JMS Queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround, if you are using ESB with your JMS queue, you can use the BAM mediator in the mediator flow to capture data from the JMS message and publish it to BAM.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We dont have a ESB... is there a possibility to put some kind of JMS Listener extension into the BAM which gets events from a Queue and forwards them to the Data Reciever ?

Comment: It can definitely be done. It can be reviewed and prioritized if you open a JIRA at https://wso2.org/jira/browse/BAM