# How do I communicate apache MQ with wso2 BAM server? (no ESB keeping it simple)

Tags: queue, wso2, wso2-bam

I am trying to get some simple web statistics using a wso2 BAM server, I have installed it, I understand how the events are defined, stored on the casssandra database etc. but I lack the most important thing: how to pass the events themselves to the BAM server?

I have programmed systems where json files are stored in a file ("queue") and my java process reads and processes them every 30 seconds, I thought this would be similar but the truth is I am pretty lost.

The port 7611 is TCP, listening.
Do I have to send the BAM server the events throught it?

Any help would be greatly apprecciated!

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, WSO2 BAM is not supported for apache mq directly. you have to use ESB or CEP to send events to BAM through thrift (Then you can use apache mq to send the events to ESB/CEP and through any of these product, you can send the events to BAM) .

But You can use the REST api to send the events to BAM which is more simple approach. Please refer the doc [1]. I thing future releases of BAM will support for jms (FYI, refer [2]).

[1] http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/BAM220/REST+API

[2] [WSO2 BAM with JMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13619867/wso2-bam-with-jms)

Thnaks,

Mohan

Comment: Thanks a lot! I finally got to send both srtream definition and events just using curl as described in http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/BAM220/REST+API  . Now I'll have to build some java to pick the data from the apache MQ out queue and feed it to the BAM server that way  :))

Answer (score 0):

BAM can get events either through REST API or through Thrift API.
7611 is the unsecured Thrift port and 7711 is the secured Thrift port by default.
As currently BAM does not have out-of-the-box Data Agent for Apache MQ, you have to write a one yourself.
If you want to publish events directly to BAM using Java you can use the DataBridge component in WSO2 code base. (i.e., use https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/4.1.0/components/data-bridge/org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift/4.1.1)

Comment: Thank you Maninda, I was having some problems using the databridge.agent libraries, the port 7611 was listening but rejected any TCP connection, I tried to use the VariableKeyValueAgent class example from the carbon svn but was not able to find the org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.AsyncDataPublisher to import... luckily there is this simple way to send events and stream definitions to the BAM server data agent using curl which works and I can start from there  :)